# Where does the system saves wallpapers in (official) Kit Kat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-7, wallpaper

I want to copy my current system-selected background from the system directory in a Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of your question is correct, your current system-cropped wallpaper is located at `/data/system/users/0` under a filename of `wallpaper`.

Comment: I went to "/", then "data" and this last folder is empty, @aureljared

Comment: Are you sure you have root access? `/data/*` is only visible to those with root privileges.

Comment: I never said it's rooted. My phone is rooted, not my tablet. So then, rooting is mandatory for doing this...

Comment: Sorry! I assumed that you were rooted since you mentioned that you were going to get the image from the *"system"* directory, but yes, rooting is mandatory for file viewing on `/data`.